# Javascript function not returning updated object

Tags: javascript, json, web-scraping, cheerio

I wrote this function and when I run it, it returns {}. When I log json in the the function passed to $('.price').filter, it shows the json object has been updated with the correct data. However, at the end of my function it returns an empty object. I don't understand what is happening. Help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');


module.exports = function scraper(url) {
    var json = {};
    request(url, function (error, response, html) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            $('.price').filter(function () {
                var data = $(this);
                json.price = data.text();
                console.log(json);
            });
        }
    });
    return json
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return json` is happening before the function you are passing to the request (the callback). The order of execution is this:

1. Make the request.
2. When the request comes back with a response, execute this function I'm giving you (line 4)
3. Return `json` (which is still empty), the request hasn't finished yet.
4. The request is finished, so it executes the function you gave it in line 4 with the response.

You can fix it by either putting what you need to do with the response inside that function, or learning to do [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). The latter is a lot cleaner and works nicely with node.

Answer (score 0):

the request is asynchronous, so the **return json** will return a empty object, you can put it in the request callback:

```
request(url, function (error, response, html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        $('.price').filter(function () {
            var data = $(this);
            json.price = data.text();
            console.log(json);
            return json;
        });
    }
});
```